# Variable Assignment: Pointers in Python and Containers in Other Languages

Tags: python, type-conversion, variable-assignment

I am reading a book, [A Whirlwind Tour of Python](http://www.oreilly.com/programming/free/a-whirlwind-tour-of-python.csp) by, [Jake VanderPlas](http://vanderplas.com/). He is explaining a consequence of "variable as pointer" in python to be aware of. He uses the following example to explain:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x
print(y) ==> [1, 2, 3]

x.append(4) 
print(y) ==> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This shows that `x` and `y` are pointing to the same object as modifying `x` changes `y` (if the object is mutable).

My question is in other languages that assign variables as containers, when you do the `y = x` assignment does that mean you are simply creating a copy of `x` with the same elements as in `x` so that when you modify `x`, `y` is unaffected?   I think that is what he implies, but its not clearly stated. But I am also wondering whether the strict type declaration in such languages has more to do with the fact that `y` would be unaffected if `x` changes?

Comment: Depends on the language.

Comment: With regards to static typing, consider this Java example: https://repl.it/repls/LimpingNoxiousShorebird